# Ace Code Editor text hide when first clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ace-editor

I'm doing a webpage to save mySQL queries in a table. Each row got an ACE CODE EDITOR with the lines of the query. First I launch de ACE CODE EDITOR on each row, and then I hide it. Later, when I click on a button, all editors became visible and non-editable. An important thing is that the div which contains ACE must have a minimum size.

When I first click into de ACE CODE EDITOR, the text on it automatically hide to the left. When you move the cursor with the keyboard key to the left, it appears again.

Here is de HTML code and the JQUERY.

```
<div class="div-consulta">
    <div id='tab_consulta_1">
        SELECT * FROM table
    </div>

    <div id='tab_comentarios_1">
      <p>Observation about the query</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JQUERY

```
//Function to start editor
AceEditor.iniciaEditor=function(div_cargar,texto){
    var id_div=$(div_cargar).attr('id');
    var editor = ace.edit(id_div);

    var tamano_fuente=15; //font size
    var num_lineas_editor=editor.session.getLength(); //lines
    var padding=10;
    var editor_total_height=(padding*2)+(tamano_fuente*num_lineas_editor);

    editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/mysql");
    editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
    editor.setFontSize(tamano_fuente);
    editor.setOptions({maxLines: Infinity}); //So many lines as the document
    editor.setValue(texto.trim(),-1); //Set cursor to the begining
    $(div_cargar).css("height",editor_total_height);
    return editor;
};

//To resize when the div is back from hide
AceEditor.resize=function(div){
    var id_div=$(div).attr('id');
    var editor=ace.edit(id_div);
    editor.resize();
};
```

Comment: You mean that when you clicked the editor the lines numbers to the left have disappeared?

Comment: No, when I click, the text lines disappear, no the line numbers

Comment: You might be instantiating the editor, which might clear the data and instantiate your editor again

Comment: please create a demo showing the problem